# echo specific part of xml string

Tags: php, xml

Assume i have the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<products>
    <product>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>Apple iPhone 7</name>
    </product>
    <product>
        <id>2</id>
        <name>Samsung Galaxy S7</name>
    </product>
</products>
```

With the following code, I'm able to print the whole xml-string:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);

echo '<pre>'.htmlentities($xml->asXML()).'</pre>';
```

I'm now looking for code to echo a ***specific part*** of the xml string, let's say product[0].

I want to be able to echo it as follows:

```
<product>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>Apple iPhone 7</name>
</product>
```

Anyone knows the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this functions:

```
<?php
    function xml2ary(&$string) {
        $parser = xml_parser_create();
        xml_parser_set_option($parser, XML_OPTION_CASE_FOLDING, 0);
        xml_parse_into_struct($parser, $string, $vals, $index);
        xml_parser_free($parser);
        $mnary=array();
        $ary=&$mnary;
        foreach ($vals as $r) {
            $t=$r['tag'];
            if ($r['type']=='open') {
                if (isset($ary[$t])) {
                    if (isset($ary[$t][0])) $ary[$t][]=array(); else $ary[$t]=array($ary[$t], array());
                    $cv=&$ary[$t][count($ary[$t])-1];
                } else $cv=&$ary[$t];
                if (isset($r['attributes'])) {foreach ($r['attributes'] as $k=>$v) $cv['_a'][$k]=$v;}
                $cv['_c']=array();
                $cv['_c']['_p']=&$ary;
                $ary=&$cv['_c'];
            } elseif ($r['type']=='complete') {
                if (isset($ary[$t])) { // same as open
                    if (isset($ary[$t][0])) $ary[$t][]=array(); else $ary[$t]=array($ary[$t], array());
                    $cv=&$ary[$t][count($ary[$t])-1];
                } else $cv=&$ary[$t];
                if (isset($r['attributes'])) {foreach ($r['attributes'] as $k=>$v) $cv['_a'][$k]=$v;}
                $cv['_v']=(isset($r['value']) ? $r['value'] : '');
            } elseif ($r['type']=='close') {
                $ary=&$ary['_p'];
            }
        }    

        _del_p($mnary);
        return $mnary;
    }
    // _Internal: Remove recursion in result array
    function _del_p(&$ary) {
        foreach ($ary as $k=>$v) {
            if ($k==='_p') unset($ary[$k]);
            elseif (is_array($ary[$k])) _del_p($ary[$k]);
        }
    }

    $string = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <products>
            <product>
                <id>1</id>
                <name>Apple iPhone 7</name>
            </product>
        <product>
            <id>2</id>
            <name>Samsung Galaxy S7</name>
        </product>
    </products>';

    $requeststring = xml2ary($string);

    echo $requeststring["products"]["_c"]["product"][0]["_c"]["id"]["_v"]; //outputs 1

?>
```

Just change ["products"] or ["product"] or ["id"] for your own result.